# Why i get module exception error when deploying on weblogic?

Tags: java, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a project on WebLogic but I get the following error:
<Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "35506599439800" for task "4". Error is: `< "weblogic.application.ModuleException">`

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EjbModuleExtensionFactory.create(EjbModuleExtensionFactory.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<14 août 2020 22 h 33 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "com.ii.hia_hiaMedControl_war_8.0".> 
<14 août 2020 22 h 33 CEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EjbModuleExtensionFactory.create(EjbModuleExtensionFactory.java:26)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.createModuleExtensions(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:264)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.initDrivenObjectArray(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:232)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:107)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please share the complete error message from the server log, not the standard output.

Comment: ####<17 août 2020 09 h 53 CEST> <Error> <Deployer> <DESKTOP-S7E07DO> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1597650820293> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "249199832230900" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException

Comment: Is there any stack trace below the error message ?

Comment: The error indicates that there is a log file with a complete stacktrace: `Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace`.  That stacktrace may help you identify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

had you tried clearing tmp and log directory, the rebooting the server, then try to redeploy it?

Comment: If you _suggest/ask_ OP to do the mentioned actions, you could have rephrased your reply so that it looked more like an answer.

Comment: Yes, i deleted cache, temp and log directories but still the same problem